# How to convert Mountain Standard Time (MST) to Mountain Daylight Time (MDT) in R

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate, dst, data-management

I am trying to convert a `datetime` variable from MST to MDT.

What I am trying to get is a new variable of `datetime` that reflects Mountain Daylight Time (MDT).

I am unsure how to start with this problem.

I am thinking to first force the original datetime with MST timezone and then transform it into MDT, however I don't know how to do that.

**UPDATE: ###############**

After some digging, I found that the original `datetime` originates as UTC -07:00, meaning it does not reflect daylight savings time. However, we need our `datetime` to follow daylight savings time.

Data where it's easy to see the time change:

```
df <- structure(list(datetime.char = c("2019-03-09 21:00", "2019-03-09 21:05", 
"2019-03-09 21:10", "2019-03-09 21:15", "2019-03-09 21:20", "2019-03-09 21:25", 
"2019-03-09 21:30", "2019-03-09 21:35", "2019-03-09 21:40", "2019-03-09 21:45", 
"2019-03-09 21:50", "2019-03-09 21:55", "2019-03-09 22:00", "2019-03-09 22:05", 
"2019-03-09 22:10", "2019-03-09 22:15", "2019-03-09 22:20", "2019-03-09 22:25", 
"2019-03-09 22:30", "2019-03-09 22:35", "2019-03-09 22:40", "2019-03-09 22:45", 
"2019-03-09 22:50", "2019-03-09 22:55", "2019-03-09 23:00", "2019-03-09 23:05", 
"2019-03-09 23:10", "2019-03-09 23:15", "2019-03-09 23:20", "2019-03-09 23:25", 
"2019-03-09 23:30", "2019-03-09 23:35", "2019-03-09 23:40", "2019-03-09 23:45", 
"2019-03-09 23:50", "2019-03-09 23:55", "2019-03-10 00:00", "2019-03-10 00:05", 
"2019-03-10 00:10", "2019-03-10 00:15", "2019-03-10 00:20", "2019-03-10 00:25", 
"2019-03-10 00:30", "2019-03-10 00:35", "2019-03-10 00:40", "2019-03-10 00:45", 
"2019-03-10 00:50", "2019-03-10 00:55", "2019-03-10 01:00", "2019-03-10 01:05", 
"2019-03-10 01:10", "2019-03-10 01:15", "2019-03-10 01:20", "2019-03-10 01:25", 
"2019-03-10 01:30", "2019-03-10 01:35", "2019-03-10 01:40", "2019-03-10 01:45", 
"2019-03-10 01:50", "2019-03-10 01:55", "2019-03-10 02:00", "2019-03-10 02:05", 
"2019-03-10 02:10", "2019-03-10 02:15", "2019-03-10 02:20", "2019-03-10 02:25", 
"2019-03-10 02:30", "2019-03-10 02:35", "2019-03-10 02:40", "2019-03-10 02:45", 
"2019-03-10 02:50", "2019-03-10 02:55", "2019-03-10 03:00", "2019-03-10 03:05", 
"2019-03-10 03:10", "2019-03-10 03:15", "2019-03-10 03:20", "2019-03-10 03:25", 
"2019-03-10 03:30", "2019-03-10 03:35", "2019-03-10 03:40", "2019-03-10 03:45", 
"2019-03-10 03:50", "2019-03-10 03:55", "2019-03-10 04:00")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -85L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(datetime.char = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

This is a screenshot of results we achieved using @d.b solution. However it doesn't exactly provide the expected output.

[image: screenshot of achieved vs. expected output]

**November month clock change**

This is dummy data for November:

```
df <- structure(list(datetime.char = c("2017-11-04 21:00:00", "2017-11-04 21:05:00", 
"2017-11-04 21:10:00", "2017-11-04 21:15:00", "2017-11-04 21:20:00", 
"2017-11-04 21:25:00", "2017-11-04 21:30:00", "2017-11-04 21:35:00", 
"2017-11-04 21:40:00", "2017-11-04 21:45:00", "2017-11-04 21:50:00", 
"2017-11-04 21:55:00", "2017-11-04 22:00:00", "2017-11-04 22:05:00", 
"2017-11-04 22:10:00", "2017-11-04 22:15:00", "2017-11-04 22:20:00", 
"2017-11-04 22:25:00", "2017-11-04 22:30:00", "2017-11-04 22:35:00", 
"2017-11-04 22:40:00", "2017-11-04 22:45:00", "2017-11-04 22:50:00", 
"2017-11-04 22:55:00", "2017-11-04 23:00:00", "2017-11-04 23:05:00", 
"2017-11-04 23:10:00", "2017-11-04 23:15:00", "2017-11-04 23:20:00", 
"2017-11-04 23:25:00", "2017-11-04 23:30:00", "2017-11-04 23:35:00", 
"2017-11-04 23:40:00", "2017-11-04 23:45:00", "2017-11-04 23:50:00", 
"2017-11-04 23:55:00", "2017-11-05 00:00:00", "2017-11-05 00:05:00", 
"2017-11-05 00:10:00", "2017-11-05 00:15:00", "2017-11-05 00:20:00", 
"2017-11-05 00:25:00", "2017-11-05 00:30:00", "2017-11-05 00:35:00", 
"2017-11-05 00:40:00", "2017-11-05 00:45:00", "2017-11-05 00:50:00", 
"2017-11-05 00:55:00", "2017-11-05 01:00:00", "2017-11-05 01:00:00", 
"2017-11-05 01:05:00", "2017-11-05 01:05:00", "2017-11-05 01:10:00", 
"2017-11-05 01:10:00", "2017-11-05 01:15:00", "2017-11-05 01:15:00", 
"2017-11-05 01:20:00", "2017-11-05 01:20:00", "2017-11-05 01:25:00", 
"2017-11-05 01:25:00", "2017-11-05 01:30:00", "2017-11-05 01:30:00", 
"2017-11-05 01:35:00", "2017-11-05 01:35:00", "2017-11-05 01:40:00", 
"2017-11-05 01:40:00", "2017-11-05 01:45:00", "2017-11-05 01:45:00", 
"2017-11-05 01:50:00", "2017-11-05 01:50:00", "2017-11-05 01:55:00", 
"2017-11-05 01:55:00", "2017-11-05 02:00:00", "2017-11-05 02:05:00", 
"2017-11-05 02:10:00", "2017-11-05 02:15:00", "2017-11-05 02:20:00", 
"2017-11-05 02:25:00", "2017-11-05 02:30:00", "2017-11-05 02:35:00", 
"2017-11-05 02:40:00", "2017-11-05 02:45:00", "2017-11-05 02:50:00", 
"2017-11-05 02:55:00", "2017-11-05 03:00:00", "2017-11-05 03:05:00", 
"2017-11-05 03:10:00", "2017-11-05 03:15:00", "2017-11-05 03:20:00", 
"2017-11-05 03:25:00", "2017-11-05 03:30:00", "2017-11-05 03:35:00", 
"2017-11-05 03:40:00", "2017-11-05 03:45:00", "2017-11-05 03:50:00", 
"2017-11-05 03:55:00", "2017-11-05 04:00:00")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-97L))
```

The interesting part is when I do March conversion there's a distinct warning message of *12 entries failing to parse.*

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(datetime = ymd_hms(df$datetime.char, tz = "MST7MDT"))
```

And in the final result if I print the df$date (refer to @d.b code in comments) the output maintains MST/MDT tz and is visible when it switches:

```
[55] "2019-03-10 01:30:00 MST" "2019-03-10 01:35:00 MST" "2019-03-10 01:40:00 MST" "2019-03-10 01:45:00 MST" "2019-03-10 01:50:00 MST" "2019-03-10 01:55:00 MST"
[61] "2019-03-10 03:00:00 MDT" "2019-03-10 03:05:00 MDT" "2019-03-10 03:10:00 MDT" "2019-03-10 03:15:00 MDT" "2019-03-10 03:20:00 MDT" "2019-03-10 03:25:00 MDT"
```

That doesn't seem to apply with November conversion

Comment: *"it has no timezone attribute yet"*: not true, it has `tzone="UTC"`, so something in your process is setting it. It's not clear to me if the times are incorrectly UTC and supposed to be US Mountain, or if you think you should be forcing MST or MDT regardless of day-of-year. Can you clarify this? (BTW: `attr(df$original, "tzone") <- "US/Mountain"` changes from UTC to mountain time.)

Answer (score 2):

An option with `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
anytime("2018-03-12 02:03:12", tz = "MST7MDT")
```